# useLocation throwing Object is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Trying to use the `useLocation` hooks introduced in react-router-dom 5.1 but throws an error - Object is not a function .

I have pasted a gist of my code below

Using

react - 16.13

react-router-dom - 5.2.0

App.js

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Redirect exact from='/' to='/home' />
    <Route id='home' path='/home' component={Home} />

  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Home.js

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function Home() {
  const [loc] = useLocation(); // throwing an error here
  console.log('ProductList -> loc', loc);
  
   return <div>Home</div>
}
```

```
Home.js:81 Uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function
    at PodList (Home.js:81)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21188)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24373)
    at react-dom.development.js:24758
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21903)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24757)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24840)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (utils.js:418)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to the latest version of react-router-dom, they have fixed it. I was facing this issue in 5.0.0 version and then I updated to 5.2.0 and it got fixed.

Comment: In most cases this works fine

Answer (score 2):

useLocation hook does not return an array but the location object that represents the current URL. You can think about it like a useState that returns a new location whenever the URL changes.

Change your code:

```
const loc = useLocation();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the examples](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Hooks/uselocation), you don't destructure `useLocation`'s return value.

Change:

```
const [loc] = useLocation();
```

to:

```
const loc = useLocation();
//    ^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− no destructuring ([])
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your component with **`withRouter`** from react-router-dom. so that you'll receive **`location`** object in props

This might not be the solution for your query, but this will solve the use case for getting location object.

Comment: Do you have a working example?